# Inserting missing quarterly earnings dates within index

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have this df:

```
            revenue   pct_yoy   pct_qoq
2020-06-30   99.721  0.479013  0.092833
2020-03-31   91.250  0.478283  0.087216
2019-12-31   83.930  0.676253  0.135094
2019-09-30   73.941       NaN  0.096657
2019-06-30   67.424       NaN  0.092293
2019-03-31   61.727       NaN  0.232814
2018-09-30   50.070       NaN       NaN
```

However, if you look at last index value with `2018`, I seem to be missing `2018-12-31` when looking at the index as a sequential quarterly time-series. The index jumps straight to `2018-9-30`.

How to ensure that any missing quarterly dates are inserted with `nan` values for their respective columns?

I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to generate a list of your own quarterly dates that includes the missing dates. Then you can use `.reindex` to re-align your dataframe to this new list of dates.

```
# Get the oldest and newest dates which will be the bounds
#  for our new Index
first_date = df.index.min()
last_date = df.index.max()

# Generate dates for every 3 months (3M) from first_date up to last_date
quarterly = pd.date_range(first_date, last_date, freq="3M")

# realign our dataframe using our new quarterly date index
#  this will fill NaN for dates that did not exist in the
#  original index
out = df.reindex(quarterly)

# if you want to order this from most recent date to least recent date 
#  do: out.sort_index(ascending=False)
print(out)
            revenue   pct_yoy   pct_qoq
2018-09-30   50.070       NaN       NaN
2018-12-31      NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-03-31   61.727       NaN  0.232814
2019-06-30   67.424       NaN  0.092293
2019-09-30   73.941       NaN  0.096657
2019-12-31   83.930  0.676253  0.135094
2020-03-31   91.250  0.478283  0.087216
2020-06-30   99.721  0.479013  0.092833
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data contains only quarter-enddates as in the sample, you may use `resample` and `asfreq` to fill missing `quarter-ends`

```
df_final = df.resample('Q').asfreq()[::-1]

Out[122]:
            revenue   pct_yoy   pct_qoq
2020-06-30   99.721  0.479013  0.092833
2020-03-31   91.250  0.478283  0.087216
2019-12-31   83.930  0.676253  0.135094
2019-09-30   73.941       NaN  0.096657
2019-06-30   67.424       NaN  0.092293
2019-03-31   61.727       NaN  0.232814
2018-12-31      NaN       NaN       NaN
2018-09-30   50.070       NaN       NaN
```